# How to not use laser data for navigation?

Tags: navigation, base-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd like to prevent the local planner from using laser data, but I still want to publish it so that I can process it elsewhere.  How can I do that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234251/how-to-not-use-laser-data-for-navigation?/) by [mitch](https://answers.ros.org/users/22960/mitch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2016-05-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/1000/jbot/) on 2016-05-13**:
Can you show us your YAML files to see the parameters you use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The easiest way to do that would be to set the `occ_dist` parameter of the local planner to zero (I assume you're using `base_local_planner`).  This won't add any extra cost for potential trajectories to enter nonzero cost cells.  I suppose you could even configure the local costmap to not have any layers, which would keep it empty.

I don't know your application, but you might find the robot will clip objects by doing something like this. The only way I see this working is if you update the global plan from `navfn` at a pretty high frequency.

I hope this helps!

---

Originally posted by [robustify](https://answers.ros.org/users/26169/robustify/) with karma: 956 on 2016-05-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0